# JQuery: Custom Attribute Keyword Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

For a project I'm using a custom attribute on elements to designate whether or not they'll have a custom template. I need the ability to select elements with a custom template based on a keyword. I've made a simplified case for demonstration.

So, for example:

```
<div jk_template="blue">Blue</div>
<div jk_template="red">Red</div>
<div jk_template="red big">Red Big</div>
```

I've tried:

```
$('[jk_template="blue"]').css('color', 'blue');
$('[jk_template="red"]').css('color', 'red');
$('[jk_template="red big"]').css('font-size','22px');
```

Unfortunately the `red big` only appears with larger font-size, but not colored red.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEuk7/)

I also want to be able to select elements that don't have the custom template based on the absence of the attribute. Is all of this possible using just JQuery selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and JQuery actually leverages [CSS 1-3 selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

To select an element with a specific attribute value substring use `[attr*=value]`:

```
$('[jk_template*="red"]').css('color', 'red');
```

To select an element without a specific attribute use the [`:not` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot):

```
$(':not([jk_template])').css('color','orange');
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tEuk7/1/)